# Setting a default input language for lightdm lock screen

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, lock-screen, language-support

My lock screen shows up after a few minutes in which I am not using the computer. This is a wanted behaviour. However, it often switches the input language to Hebrew, or perhaps just taking the last chosen input language.

In almost 100% of the times, I find myself trying to log in Hebrew, failing, and then logging in again in English. This is annoying.

Moreover, unlike in Ubuntu 12.04, in my current Ubuntu 14.04 I don't see in the password input field any sign that this is Hebrew that I enter now - only in the corner of the screen. It still types from left to right, as if it was English.

Can I somehow force the lock page to choose English by default..? Perhaps by some hook?

Comment: The login screen shows up? Don't you mean the lock screen? Those two components are managed by two different pieces of software.

Comment: I think it's the lock screen you are talking about, as @the_Seppi said. Possibly you hit [bug #1286910](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1286910).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, you're probably right. Do you wish to post it as an answer so we can close this question?

Comment: Sure, just did.

Comment: ... and a moderator deleted it ...

Comment: That's weird. I haven't read it, but it was probably qualified to be a valid answer.

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem. (With Hebrew as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you hit [bug #1286910](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1286910).

[George Karakostas](https://launchpad.net/~gckarakostas) has [reported there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1286910/comments/11) that [Martin Jurča](https://launchpad.net/~mato-jurca)'s [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1240198/comments/19) to [bug 1240198](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1240198) worked for this bug also.

> Here's an easy fix:
>
> 1. open terminal
> 2. run `ibus-setup`
> 3. open the extra settings (the last tab)
> 4. check the "use system keyboard layout" checkbox
>
> Now, how about you guys (yes, you, Canonical) make this the default
>   settings? All I know about it is that it (probably) stores its config
>   in gconf, but I cannot find it, so I cannot give you a patch.

So you should attempt that fix for your problem, too. (Note, however, that [Mikhail V. Golubev](https://launchpad.net/~mvgolubev) has [reported this workaround did not work in his case](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1286910/comments/12). So this is apparently a usable solution only for some instances of this problem.)

Comment: This popped in the low-quality queue. The bug report comments suggest a possible solution, so could you add that as well to fill out this answer?

Comment: @muru: Originally it was just a comment, but I made it an answer since the OP asked me to. I don't know enough about the topic to advocate a solution/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightdm when you face this problem:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>F7</kbd>)
2. Enter your account username and password and go to the terminal
3. Enter `sudo service lightdm restart`

Then you will be redirected to another main lock page whose language is English by default.